# Help me interpret my dmiencode results to figure out what kind of RAM slots I have

Tags: memory, ram

My motherboard has four DIMM slots for RAM (labeled XMM1, XMM2, XMM3, and XMM4). They look identical (one notch near the middle) except 1 & 3 are black plastic, 2 & 4 are white. I have only one DIMM in right now, in slot 1.

I'd assume they're all the same, but my *dmiencode* output seems to indicate that 1 is DDR2, while the rest are just regular DDR?

dmiencode --type 17 output:

```
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.3 present.

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0033
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: XMM1
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 400 MHz (2.5 ns)
    Manufacturer: JEDEC ID:C1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    Serial Number: 23211205
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: 64T128020HU5A

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0033
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: XMM2
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: JEDEC ID:
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0033
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: XMM3
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR                                ######## Not DDR2?
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: JEDEC ID:
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number:  

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0033
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: XMM4
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: JEDEC ID:
    Serial Number:  
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number:
```

I need to buy new RAM as the current ram is probably wrong (found it lying around). What type of RAM does my motherboard take? Once I figure out what type it is I'm just going to buy the max speed even though I'm sure it's a slower mobo.

Comment: Now you've got DDR2-800 RAM (aka PC6400 DDR2) in there. Why do you say it's probably wrong?

Comment: I just found it in my pile of scrapped parts. It's probably too fast or too slow or some other spec is off, I don't really know how to match ram to a mobo, I just see if it fits and then see if it boots. Buying ram is different, I'm hoping to get the right kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two sets of colors in order to help you match them in pairs, if you wish to. Other than that, they are all the same.

The `Type: DDR` has a valid value as long as memory is installed to a slot. If there is no memory there, then it gives the stock `DDR` value.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying they're probably all DDR2?

Comment: Exactly, there are all DDR2 capable.